# IIS Adding application to website does not work, but separate website works

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When I add an api application to one of my websites on IIS locally, testing the api just returns errors saying to change the nuget packages to use the same ones as the main website. Eventually once the errors are fixed, I get a 500 error afterwards.
When I create a new website on IIS and I test the api, it works.

Would I need to change something within my web.config got the api web application?

I am creating this with asp.net framework.

Comment: The inheritance nature of sites/apps makes it pretty difficult to run an ASP.NET app under another, so you should go multiple sites if you want to keep simplicity. To manipulate URLs of multiple sites, set up a reverse proxy in front and all kind of flexibility is there.

Comment: If it is too difficult to run an ASP.NET app under another, what is the best thing to use for Applications in IIS?